# Can't create new partition as disk sector count incorrect?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I used `dd` to copy a bootable 8GB USB disk image `16.04-server` to a 1TB drive, which boots perfectly. I want to create a new swap partition at the end of the drive, before extending the capacity of the root partition to fill the drive.

Trouble is, the drive `/sda/` seems only reach enough sectors for an 8GB drive.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6d9e46a7

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 11780095 11778048  5.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       11782142 15972351  4190210    2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       11782144 15972351  4190208    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

It should be this

```
# mdadm file partitioning
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/md0p1              63 1952202734 1952202672 930.9G 83 Linux
/dev/md0p2      1952202735 1953246959    1044225 509.9M  5 Extended
/dev/md0p5      1952202798 1953246959    1044162 509.9M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

// this drive is part of an old raid1 array but is same size.
```

I attempted to use command line `parted` ank mkpart with the following settings, but it gave me the following error.

```
(parted) mkpart                                                     
Partition type?  primary/logical? logical                                 
File system type?  [ext2]? linux-swap
Start? 1952202735
Error: The location 1952202735 is outside of the device /dev/sda.
```

Would greatly appreciate being pointed in the appropriate direction.

Comment: I suspect that the old RAID signatures are confusing the partitioning tool. Try to wipe 1. the first mibibyte of the drive and if not enough, wipe more, for example 8 GB (the part of the drive, that you were overwriting when `dd`-ing. Overwrite = write zeros with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=...` but **double check that you get the correct target device**. Don't let `dd`act as 'Data Destroyer'. Maybe the 8 GB drive has a different sector size than the 1 TB drive, which means that you should create partitions separately and *copy the directories and files on the file level*, not with `dd`.

Comment: If not RAID, you should remove the RAID meta-data:  `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` But dd copies exact size to exact size. Some have had to use drive mfg tools to resize as nothing else works. Often better easier to just reinstall & copy settings & other data. If no swap partition does this work? `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`

Comment: Thanks! I `dd`ed the image onto the 1TB drive using `bs=4M`. I have checked the byte site on the 8GB drive and it's `512/512 (logical / physical)` this compares to `512 / 4096` on the 1TB drive. Would that affect it?    I'm hoping to not over write the image at the start of the disk, as It's a boot partition. so `dd`ing over the first mibibyte would possibly ruin it?

Comment: Yes, that would probably 'affect it'. In cases like this it is probably easier to go the way suggested by @oldfred, to reinstall & copy settings & other data.